# .whl file for pyaudio in python 3.12

Tags: installation, project, pyaudio, python-wheel, python-3.12

I have been working on an ai assistant project for which I needed the pyaudio tool, but to install pyaudio certain .whl files are available online for previous python versions but not for the latest version i.e 3.12.

I tried going online and searching but couldn't find anything for the latest version

Comment: Use Python 3.11. Or compile PyAudio from sources.